# rendering bloom effect

Tags: opengl, bloom

I am making a game which has a playing arena which renders a lot of grid of lines. The lines are colored. Now to have a good effect I thought of giving it the tron like effect of glowing lines. Now after surfing the net I came to know that I could achieve that effect using the bloom effect. Now for that I needed to GLSL in opengl which I have read to some extent but now I want to clear certain doubts of mine.

What is the difference between a shader having ".verg" and ".frag" extension against a ".glsl" shader?

Also given a ".glsl" shader. How can I get the ".verg" and ".frag" shader from it?

Any good tutorial for implementing bloom effect on the edges of a cube or edges of a rectangle?

I am using OpenGL and am programming on Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Also: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18662/how-can-i-create-an-efficient-bloom-shader-with-glsl and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/how-is-this-lighting-effect-done and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18594/how-can-i-make-this-style-of-2d-glowing-graphics

Comment: This seems to me to be two separate questions: "What do I do with `.glsl`?" and "How do I implement bloom?" Since there are duplicates for the latter, perhaps this question should become the former?